# binding a list of class to a data grid UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I would like to display this object(Node) in a data grid (coordinate is a custom class that literally describes a coordinate) -

```
 public class Node
    {
        [JsonRequired]
        private bool finished;
        [JsonRequired]
        private readonly string type;
        [JsonRequired]
        private coordinate starting_point = null;
        [JsonRequired]
        private string ID = "";
        [JsonRequired]
        public coordinate Final_Dest = null;
        [JsonRequired]
        public List<coordinate> check_points = new List<coordinate>();
        [JsonRequired]
        private string Metadata = "";
        [JsonRequired]
        private readonly SimpleMarkerSymbol symbol;
        [JsonRequired]
        private int Vmax;
        [JsonRequired]
        public int Amax;
        [JsonRequired]
        private int slope_max;
        [JsonRequired]
        private int slope_min;
        [JsonRequired]
        private int terrein_rank_reject;
        [JsonRequired]
        private int affinity_to_stay_in_group;
        [JsonRequired]
        public int GroupID;
        [JsonRequired]
        public bool coomplitionflag = false;
```

this is what I tried to do -

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            selected_nodes = (comboclass)e.Parameter;
            postioning_index = selected_nodes.Get_index();
            Node[] array_of_nodes = selected_nodes.Get_node_array();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = Create_list(array_of_nodes);//this function creates a list of nodes          
        }
        public static List<Node> Create_list(Node[] array_nodes)
        {
            var node_coll = new List<Node>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array_nodes.Length; i++)
            {
                node_coll.Add(array_nodes[i]);
            }
            return node_coll;
        }
```

and for some reason when I execute it only shows the field -type on the data grid

Comment: did you set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` in your xaml or in code behind?

Comment: yes it still doesn't work ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> binding a list of class to a data grid UWP

If you want to bind the `Node` instance, you need implement the public field's set get method.
Please edit your class like the following.

```
public class Node
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public coordinate Final_Dest { get; set; }   
    .......
}
```

For more detail please refer [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) document.

Comment: its worked  partially , since the object coordinate is displayed as =  SimuPro.coordinate